# Regarding React router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

Hope you are doing good. I have one question regarding react routing. I have 5 components defined in app.js file after one by one and created route for that as shown in app.js file and created header for that as well as shown in header.js file. But the problem is this when I should click on the 4th component defined in header then focus should come near to 4th component, instead of displaying 4th component below 5th component. for reference I'm giving one website link I want to make routing like this website, if you didn't understand my question.

```
Refernce Website link
https://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Ceevee_2_0_0/
```

```
Note: I have completed this issue, for solution please check this link
https://github.com/pajjwal1/Resume
```

```
***App.jS***
import './App.css';
import { Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './Components/Header/header';
import Home from './Components/Home/home'
import Bg from './Asset/header-bg.jpg'
import About from './Components/About/about'
import Technical from './Components/Technical/technical'
import Project from './Components/Project/project'
import Education from './Components/Education/education'
import Personal from './Components/Personal/personal'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Home background = {Bg}/>
      <About />
      <Technical />
      <Project />
      <Education />
      <Personal />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/home' exact component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path='/about' component={About}></Route>
        <Route path='/technical' component={Technical}></Route>  
        <Route path='/project' component={Project}></Route>  
        <Route path='/education' component={Education}></Route>  
        <Route path='/personal' component={Personal}></Route>  
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
***header.js***
import React from 'react';
import '../Header/header.css'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
function header(){
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="header_center">
                {/* <p>Home</p>
                <p>About</p>
                <p>Technical Expertiese</p>
                <p>Projects</p>
                <p>Qualification</p>
                <p>Personal Details</p> */}
                <NavLink className='nav-item' to='/home'>Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-item' to='/about'>About</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-item' to='/technical'>Technical Expertiese</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-item' to='/project'>Projects</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-item' to='/education'>Qualification</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='nav-item' to='/personal'>Personal Details</NavLink>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want. Do you want to scroll to the component when you click on the nav item of the header?
In this case, you should use a hash router.
Please put id to each component that you want to navigate on the page.
And use # for hash navigate.
For example, if you want to navigate to `projects` component, use  like this.

```
<Link to="/#projects"> Projects </Link>
```

And have you wrapped your app component with Router?

```
import { createBrowserHistory as history } from 'history'
...

<Router history={history()}>
   ...
   <App />
   ...
</Router>
```

I hope this helps you to solve your problem.

If it doesn't work for you, please contact me.
I'm sure I can solve this kind of problem.

I will list the things that I updated on your project.

#app.js
Remove Switch wrapper with children

```
...
{/* <Switch>
        <Route path='/home' exact component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path='/about' component={About}></Route>
        <Route path='/technical' component={Technical}></Route>  
        <Route path='/#project' component={Project}></Route>  
        <Route path='/#education' component={Education}></Route>  
        <Route path='/personal' component={Personal}></Route>  
      </Switch> */}
...
```

#header.js
Please use a tag instead of Navlink

```
<a className='nav-item' href='/#home'>Home</a>
                <a className='nav-item' href='/#about'>About</a>
                <a className='nav-item' href='/#technical'>Technical Expertiese</a>
                <a className='nav-item' href='/#project'>Projects</a>
                <a className='nav-item' href='/#education'>Qualification</a>
                <a className='nav-item' href='/#personal'>Personal Details</a>
...
```

And you should put id on every component as like as the `project` component.

If it doesn't work, please let me know or invite me to your GitHub repo.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Oscar  Yeah I want that only it should scroll to that component. So suppose in project I have added id to that main div after return line and added same div in Navlink and route both but it is not working.

Comment: Did you add the id to the `project` component?

Comment: Yes @Oscar like this 
```
    return (
        <div className="modal_image" id="project">
            <h1><u>In Capgemini</u></h1>
            <Row className="modal_class">
                <div className="projectone col-md-6">
                    <h3>Project 1</h3>
                    <img onClick={onOpenModal} src={MichaelPage} />
                    <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
                        <h2>Michael Page- UI Developer</h2>
                        <p style={{color:"black"}}>
                        <ul>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your app component with <Router> hoc? I've updated my answer, please have a check and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I have wrapped it with BrowserRouter like this I'm doing
`<BrowserRouter history={history()}>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>`
But still it's not working

Comment: Can I check your project? please give me your git rep.

Comment: Please avoid coding standard as I'm new in React so I'm trying to make something this is my github repo https://github.com/pajjwal1/Resume  and please tell me where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: Hi Have you checked?

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed your project. It works, I will update my answer, please have a check.

Comment: Please send me mail solution for one Menu item as I'm not getting i tried it too much, my mail is prajjwalkumar033@gmail.com, That would be great for me thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if it works or not.
I will delete the git rep after 1 day.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for your help, once again thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to scroll down to the component when you click the navigation item on header?
For that you can use hash router.
For more detail about that, you can reference this site.
https://paulgrajewski.medium.com/using-context-and-hashrouter-in-react-87afcefc5966

Is it helpful for you?

Comment: No bro not coming I tried this way as well